# Availability of @vars, #tables and ## tables on recursive procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, stored-procedures

If I call a stored procedure which recursively calls itself, I am wondering if @vars, #tables and ##tables have non-conflicting instance copies. I am *guessing* @vars and #tables are ok, but ## should create problems.

I think the question further expands as: When a sp calls itself, does it create a new session?

Comment: My question would be why do you need a recursive procedure in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Variables are scoped to one level (so they are not visible to nested calls), #temp tables are scoped to the session, ##temp tables are scoped globally. There is no way in T-SQL to even create a new session (even `EXEC` creates a new batch, but not a new session). Well, you could create a scheduled job on the fly (or maybe use `OPENROWSET` with the local server), but that's cheating.

Be wary of creating temp tables in stored procedures that nest, though: you'll run into trouble if you're not careful. Specifically, [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#temporary-tables):

> A local temporary table created within a stored procedure or trigger
>   can have the same name as a temporary table that was created before
>   the stored procedure or trigger is called. However, if a query
>   references a temporary table and two temporary tables with the same
>   name exist at that time, it is not defined which table the query is
>   resolved against. Nested stored procedures can also create temporary
>   tables with the same name as a temporary table that was created by the
>   stored procedure that called it. However, for modifications to resolve
>   to the table that was created in the nested procedure, the table must
>   have the same structure, with the same column names, as the table
>   created in the calling procedure.

That means the "obvious" case where you create "the same" temp table in every step of the nesting works as you'd expect: every nested call has its "own" table and won't see the parent table. If you *don't* create the table in a nested call, though, you'll get the parent table, and if you create one with a different structure (for whatever reason) you can actually get a compilation error when SQL Server detects this bizarre set of circumstances.

You can therefore both use a temp table as way to keep state across calls, or specifically not do that by "recreating" it, but it's up to you to keep things sane.

Comment: How does the quote support your claim "every nested call has its "own" table and won't see the parent table"?

Comment: @philipxy: the last sentence implies that "if the table has the same structure with the same column names", then "modifications resolve to the table that was created in the nested procedure", and in fact this scenario is demonstrated in the docs right after this paragraph. I admit the text could be a lot clearer. (Also, I simply tested it, although it's quite true that you can't always take the result of a practical test as 100% reproducible in T-SQL.)

Comment: The last sentence does not imply that. It says that to access the innermost table a matching heading is necessary. Nothing in the quote says what is sufficient. The author of the last sentence might have been trying to say that it is sufficient, but that's not what what they wrote says. And it being sufficient would contradict what is said earlier, in the second sentence.

Comment: @philipxy: sorry, I didn't write it. Feel free to raise an issue on the page itself, or write up your own answer (or question!) with these concerns. From the text, the observed behavior and by what would be actually useful, I feel pretty confident inferring that, if a stored procedure recursively calls itself and, in every execution, does not access a particular temporary table until it has created that temporary table, the scopes of those tables will nest in the expected way. More complicated situations with other outcomes exist, but are not immediately relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

- All recursions are in the same *batch*
- Each stored procedure (recursion) has it's own *scope* with in the *batch*

In simple terms

- A connections has many batches (one after the other)
- A batch has many scopes (each code unit such stored proc, function, etc)

So

- @vars are scoped to that code unit = Ok per recursion
- #tables are scoped to the connection = NOT Ok, visible to recursions
- ##tables are scoped to all using connections = NOT Ok, visible to recursions